# Removing empty ULs

Tags: jquery, loops, html-lists

I need to remove empty ULs and those LIs which contains empty ULs so I use this script

```
    $("ul").each(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            if (elem.children().length == 0) {
                elem.parent().remove();
            }
        }
    );
```

After runing the script it can happen that I get empty ULs as a result so I need to run script again. Can I somehow loop it untill all empty ULs are removed?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you:

```
while($('ul:empty, li:empty').length) {
    $('ul:empty, li:empty').remove();
}
```

[JsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/asorom/edit#javascript,html,live)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i don't understand fully your question but If you need to re-run the command you can create a function:

```
var clearUls = function(){
    $("ul").each(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            if (elem.children().length == 0) {
                elem.parent().remove();
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And then you can call it as many times as you want.